# Reducing a list by max and min of values

Tags: java, mapreduce, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Lets say i have a list like this ->

```
[(ab, 2), (bc, 3), (ab, 5), (bc, 7)]
```

and i want to convert it into a list like this ->

```
[(ab, 3), (bc, 4)]
```

where value is max-min of values for these keys. I have to do this for a very large list using spark. I am reading this list into an RDD. Please see the code below

```
class Record { String key; int value; }

JavaRDD<String> logLines = sc.textFile(logFile);
JavaRDD<Record> records = logLines.map(Logs::parseLine).cache();
```

I know i can write two reducers which find max and min values for each key. And then just iterate over the list doing max-min. But is there a better way ? Please help

**Edit**:
Solved it like following.

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> minValues = records.mapToPair(rec -> new Tuple2<>(rec.getKey(), rec.getValue())).reduceByKey(MIN_REDUCER);
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> maxValues = records.mapToPair(rec -> new Tuple2<>(rec.getKey(), rec.getValue())).reduceByKey(MAX_REDUCER);

List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> diffvalues = minValues.join(maxValues).map(record -> new Tuple2<>(record._1(), record._2()._2() - record._2()._1())).collect();

System.out.println(diffvalues);
```

Comment: You can use `aggregateByKey` with `Tuple2<int, int>(Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE)` as a zero value.